# Update all tables containing column name where the field is something specific

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know [a similar question](http://Update%20all%20tables%20containing%20column%20name) has been asked before but i was wonder if there is any way that you could run an update across all tables in a database where a column name exists but only for fields with a specific entry.

So for example `UPDATE <table> SET <column_name> = '123' where <column_name> = '124'`

Thanks in advance for everyones help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will require some dynamic SQL and potentially could make use of a while/do loop.
Basically the idea will be to figure our how to define your list of tables and column names.  If you really are just looking for a list of tables where a column name exists, you will probably want to make use of the sys.syscolumns table to query the column names.

```
SELECT o.name
FROM sys.syscolumns c
    JOIN sys.sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE UPPER(c.name) = 'Description'
```

From there you can build your dynamic sql statement.

```
DECLARE @sqltext VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @UpdateValue VARCHAR(30) = 'SetThisValue'

SELECT @sqltext = ISNULL(@sqltext,'') + 'UPDATE '+o.name + CHAR(10) + ' SET     [YourColumnNameHere] = ' + @UpdateValue + CHAR(10)
    + ' WHERE [YourColumnNameHere] = [Somevalue]'
FROM sys.syscolumns c
    JOIN sys.sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE UPPER(c.name) = 'Description'

PRINT @sqltext
EXEC sp_executesql @sqltext
```

I have the print statement in there to help you get the @sqltext exactly the way you want it.  Once you have it as you want, use the EXEC sp_executesql line to actually run the output of the @sqltext.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way of putting a where clause on this? Sorry, i haven't got A LOT OF experience with dynamic SQL

Comment: There definitely is.  I forgot to add that.  I will edit to add it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL to build your update statements like this.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE [' + name + '] SET <column_name> = ''123'' where <column_name> = ''124'''
FROM sys.tables
```